# Proving subgroup of $Aut(\Bbb C^2)$ that fixes a specific curve is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^6 \times \Bbb Z^3 $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

So, I have the curve $C = V(y^3 - x^6 + y^6) \subset \Bbb C^2$.

I want to prove that, if $G= \{ \varphi = (f_1,f_2) \in Aut(\Bbb C^2):\varphi(C) = C,$ $ deg(f_i) = 1  \}$, then $G \simeq \Bbb Z^6  \times \Bbb Z^3$.

From a previous exercise, I know that such a $\varphi$ must send $0$ to itself, that is, $\varphi$ is linear. Using that, I was able to find a subgroup $H \simeq \Bbb Z^6  \times \Bbb Z^3 $ of $G$.

This is $H$:

$H= \{\varphi \in Aut(\Bbb C^2) : \varphi(x,y)=(e^\frac{2k\pi i}6x, e^\frac{2j\pi i}3y),0 \leq k \leq 5, 0 \leq j \leq 2  \}$

It is easy to see that $H \simeq \Bbb Z^6  \times \Bbb Z^3$ (sending $(\bar{k}, \bar{j})$ to $(e^\frac{2\bar{k}\pi i}6x, e^\frac{2\bar{j}\pi i}3y)$).

I have not been able to prove that $G=H$, and I'd rather not resort to brute force (taking an arbitrary automorphism $(ax + by, cx + dy)$ and substituting in the equation for the curve doesn't look very promising to me). Is there a way to circumvent this? Any tips will do, I don't need a full answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a hint, which should simplify the calculation. A linear automorphism preserves the homogeneous terms. So, such a $\phi$ must take $y^3$ to a constant multiple of $y^3$ and similarly with $x^6-y^6$.